# Página "site-analytics", "visitas" vs "visitas"?

Tags: bug, tradução

Eu realmente não tenho acesso ao `/site-analytics` em outros sites devido a baixa reputação, então não sei como está escrito o termo "visitas". No pt.stackoverflow.com, eu tenho acesso (requer 25k para poder acessar https://pt.stackoverflow.com/site-analytics), mas o texto está confuso (ou eu que não entendi). Está assim:

[image: tráfego]

O "novos visitantes" (cor verde) é fácil de entender, o que não entendo é a diferença de visitas na cor laranja e visitas na cor azul.

Qual a diferença entre ambos? Seria falta de tradução?

Comment: Deve ser erro de tradução de *views*.

Comment: @bigown Provavelmente, você tem acesso em outro site da rede?

Comment: Não tenho não..

Comment: Atualmente só 13 usuários do site tem acesso a isso. Os 11 que têm reputação maior que 25000 e mais o Math e o Gabe. Logo, esse é um recurso para pouquíssimos, portanto é natural que tenha recebido pouca atenção.

Comment: Eu tenho acesso ao do codegolf. O laranja é "page views", o azul é "visits" e o verde é "new visits".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Eu tenho acesso ao do codegolf.
Os termos originais do inglês são:

- Laranja é "page views"
- Azul é "visits".
- Verde é "new visits".

Comment: Mesmo que não corrijam a tradução ainda, pelo menos a sua resposta irá servir de orientação.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento E observe que mesmo o verde está errado no português. O correto seria "novas visitas" e não "novos visitantes".

Comment: Tenho que voltar a olhar o transifex, me cadastrei mas ainda não usei, vou tentar mandar a proposta lá.

Answer (score 5):

Alterei a tradução de "page views" de *visitas* para *page views*. Acho que em inglês mesmo é mais claro, é um termo técnico. Falta o Gabe validar minha edição e sair uma nova build do site.